# PHP append a variable to the end of a string

Tags: php, html, laravel

So here I want to append the id of the currently logged in user to the name of a table, like for example Rating_User_1, but the 1 here comes from the id of the logged in user. I assigned the id of the logged in user to $id, as shown below in the code, and append it to the table column name, but this doesn't work. I tried echoing the $id by itself and it works (i.e. it spits out the id of the logged in user but that's not what I want), but when I try to append it to the string in order to "emulate" the table name it doesn't work. Any tips on workarounds?

```
@foreach($data as $data)
  <tr>
    <td> {{$loop->iteration}} </td> <!-- add number to the row -->
    <td>
      <a href="{{ Url('reply_thread') }}/{{ $data->id }}" class="text" >{{ $data->Judul }}</a>
    </td>
    <td><?php $id = Auth::user()->id;
      echo $data->Rating_user_[$id]; ?> </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

My controller:

```
function threads() {
    $data=Thread::all();
    return view('thread.thread', ['data'=>$data]);
}
```

and some of the tables in the table Thread has columns named Rating_user_1, Rating_user_2, etc.

Comment: show your controller code, where its returning data.

Comment: @Webinion edited my question

Comment: Why create a separate column for each new user? are you creating EAV design?

Comment: how about simply `<td>Rating_user_{{ $Auth::user()->id }}</td>` ?

Comment: Please remember to check an answer as correct (there are multiple valid ones) so the question is closed and other users can identify the answer as a solution to their problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Asur how do I create such check mark?

Comment: @aldo Next to an answer, below the votes you have a green tick, that's how you mark an answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable expansion sometimes needs curly braces to function properly. The following should work:

```
echo $data->{'Rating_user_' . $id}
```

- See [Variable Parsing - Complex Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for info on "curly brace" variable expansion.
- While it doesn't look like you need it here, [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) may also be useful to read up on. (aka, `$a = 'b'; $b = 'hello'; echo $$a; // Same as "echo $b", outputs 'hello'`)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to achieve this, the first would be to call the property/method with the name stored in a variable:

```
$tableName = 'Rating_user_' . $id;
$tableName = "Rating_user_$id";
$data->$tableName;
```

You could also use curly braces to make a *hot concat* on the property/method call itself as @romellem suggested:

```
$data->{'Rating_user_' . $id} 
$data->{"Rating_user_$id"}
```

If you are going to access the `$data->Rating_user` more than once I would recommend you the first approach, if not the second one is okey aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
@foreach($data as $data)
  <tr>
    <td> {{$loop->iteration}} </td> <!-- add number to the row -->
    <td>
      <a href="{{ Url('reply_thread') }}/{{ $data->id }}" class="text" >
        {{ $data->Judul }}
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ $data->{'Rating_user_' . $id} }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is almost correct, and I think it's better if you use double curly than use echo like:

```
@foreach($data as $data)
     <tr>
        <td> {{$loop->iteration}} </td> <!-- add number to the row -->
        <td>
           <a href="{{ Url('reply_thread') }}/{{ $data->id }}" class="text" >{{ $data->Judul }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $data->{'Rating_user_' . Auth::id()} }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```